# Velocity.js version 2.0 not animating

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

Using Velocity version 2.0, the element is being removed from the DOM after about 1500ms, but there is no animation. It just pops in and out of view.

```
var jQueryObject = document.jQuery(element);
    jQueryObject.velocity("slideDown", {duration: 1500})
        .velocity("slideUp", {duration: 4000})
        .then(function(){element.remove()});
```

Link to the docs: http://velocityjs.org/#fade

Answer (score 0):

Velocity V2 is open beta - this isn't supported yet. I'm working on the sequences right now, and this will be back in within the next week or two (along with an improved API for it).

Please note - supported commands are in the wiki on GitHub.

Comment: Just wondering if the "slideUp", "slideDown" sequences are implemented yet?

Comment: All of the css sequences from animate.css are now in there - https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/ - but not documented or with full tests yet - that gives "slideOutUp" and "slideInDown" which I think are what you're looking for - the next release is likely to be this weekend when they'll get documented and put on NPM etc